# Nested for-loop giving repeated final results

Tags: python, list, loops

I have a directory with a lot of files that I am trying to process the fractal dimension of, but in trying to make a loop to get all of the data in one large list to be able to export it to a csv file later, but when I go through my loop, the lists that are in my master-list are all the same.

```
for n in range(5,11):
    for s in range(1,3):
        fracList.clear()
        for x in dir_list:
            y = x.split('_')
            if 'PPG' in y and 'N'+str(n) in y and 'Seg'+str(s) in y:
                fracList.append(hfd.fracDim(path+"\\"+x))
        else:
            cols.append(fracList)
```

dir_list is a list that contains all files in my directory

path is the path to the directory

cols is my "master-list" as of now

fracList is meant to contain the fractal dimensions of the relative instance (further explained below)

I have hundreds of files and they are of EEG and PPG values.
They are of the format: *Nature**N*Seg**.txt

For example, a file could look like: Joe_Nature_EEG_N5_Seg1_Ch2_fl10.txt for an EEG file
or Joe_Nature_PPG_N5_Seg1_fl10.txt for a PPG file

I have N (sound number) values from 1 to 10 but am not interested in 2, 3, or 4

I have Seg (30 second interval) values of 1 and 2 for every N for every person

I have a program that calculates the fractal dimension (imported as hfd) given the location of a txt file

I am trying to get a list of lists of the fractal dimensions of every N-Seg combination (there are 35 people, so every list in the list should have 35 elements).

As for my problem, when running my loop, it seems that cols has 12 more items, which are all lists, but they are all the same list and are the last list that was calculated.

Example: cols contains [[1.002372934, 1.0238912673, ... , 1.0156723782], [1.002372934, 1.0238912673, ... , 1.0156723782], [1.002372934, 1.0238912673, ... , 1.0156723782], ... , [1.002372934, 1.0238912673, ... , 1.0156723782]]

All of the lists should be different and I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: Yes, that is supposed to be that way. It should get done with appending fracList, then append fracList to cols. cols is a list of fracList's.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple coding error.  Consider this simplification:

```
fracList = []
cols = []

for x in range(3):
    fracList.clear()
        
    for y in range(4):
        fracList.append(x + y)
        
    cols.append(fracList)

print(cols)
```

The output is:

```
[[2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

Because we've appended three pointers to `fracList` onto `cols`.  All those pointers are the same and show the final state of `fracList`.  We either need to append a different incarnation of `fracList` each time:

```
cols = []

for x in range(3):
    fracList = []

    for y in range(4):
        fracList.append(x + y)
        
    cols.append(fracList)

print(cols)
```

Or, copy the contents of `fracList` to a unique list before we append:

```
fracList = []
cols = []

for x in range(3):
    fracList.clear()
        
    for y in range(4):
        fracList.append(x + y)
        
    cols.append(list(fracList))  # append a copy

print(cols)
```

If the output we really wanted is:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5]]
```